# Multiple lines of text rich text editor not working chrome

Tags: 2013, rte, chrome, multiple-lines-of-text, ie

First time I've come across this issue, so I'm wondering if it is a known bug and if there are any workarounds.

I have a 'Multiple Lines of Text' field with Rich Text enabled. In IE, I get the editor toolbar on top of the field. In Chrome it is not there. What's up with that? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What version of IE are you running? Is this created programmaticly?

Comment: Running IE8. It's an OOB field and the screen shot is from NewForm.aspx

Comment: We had a simlar issue with SP 2007 / 2010 and IE 9 (worked) vs. IE 10 (did not work) when working with rich-text fields. The solution was to set the document mode in IE 10 back to IE 9.

Comment: But it works in IE. It doesn't in Chrome. Do you think setting the doc mode to IE 9 will fix it in Chrome? I doubt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Rich Text editor is only supported in IE browser, thus they wont work as a RTE in Chrome or Firefox, rather they can work as a simple text editor. Here is the link to the Source -

[SharePoint Rich Text Editor not working in Firefox and Chrome](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6482efb-72e1-4536-a3cb-153d838744a4/sharepoint-rich-text-editor-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: little late to the party but I'll take it, thanks

Comment: **Cheers !!!!!!!!**